# SQL Nested Query Homework

Tags: sql, subquery

Given :

InsuranceCompanies  (**cid**, name, phone, address)

Doctors (**did**, name, specialty, address, phone, age, cid)

Patients (**pid**, name, address, phone, age, gender, cid)

Visits     (**vid**, did, pid, date, description)

Where:

```
cid - Insurance Company code
did - doctor code
pid - patient code
vid - code of visit
```

And a TASK : Find doctors (did, name) with number of visits (during this year) less than average number of visits to all doctors during this year.

My attempt is:

```
SELECT  D.did, D. name
FROM    Doctor D,Visit V
WHERE   V.did = D.did   and   D.did = CV.did   and   CV.visits <
                (SELECT AVG ( CV.visits) 
                 FROM   (SELECT V1.did AS did,COUNT(V1.vid) AS visits
                         FROM   Visit V1
                         WHERE  V1.date LIKE '%2012' 
                         GROUP BY   V1.did) AS CV)
```

Comment: Rather than ask us, you should create some sample data and test it! But no, for a start that's not the correct way to test a date's year component, your brackets don't match up, CV doesn't exist at the first place you're using it and you'll return more than one row for each doctor. Also which database are you using? There's small variations in SQL syntax for nested queries.

Comment: I Really wish i could do that! but i downloaded SQL Server 2012 and its so advanced that i cant even manage to use it... it doesnt even let me login my own computer!

Comment: as far as i know we use SQL 1999

Comment: No, that ought to just work - the user you used to install it should have admin permissions automatically. Do you definitely have the service started? Open SQL Server Management Studio and try connecting to `(local)` or `localhost` if that doesn't work.

Comment: Without checking the logic, I think I can see two typos in your attempt: `LIKE %2012` should be `LIKE '%2012'`, and you're missing a close bracket at the end.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum even easier - use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @ Benjamin Gruenbaum that doesnt sound simple... do you have a step by step video or a tutorial for that?

Comment: @Bridge thanks! that seem freindly... im gonna try and use it!

Comment: @OfekRon and once you've started playing with some queries, you can share the link to it on here and other people can have a play with your example code directly, without having to set anything up themselves.

Comment: For what I can see from your query, your CV table isn't defined in your upper level query, so it wouldn't work if you use it there. So the "D.did = CV.did and CV.visits <..." part of the query will cause an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BIG THANKS TO Bridge Who shared the most beautifull and user freindly SQL commands visualator ever!

Databse Exemple : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e85c7/3

Solution using views:

```
CREATE VIEW  ThisYear AS 
    SELECT v.pid,v.vid,v.did
    FROM Visits v
     WHERE v.date LIKE '%2012';

CREATE VIEW DoctorsVisitCount AS
    SELECT v.did, COUNT(v.vid) as c
    FROM ThisYear v
    GROUP BY v.did;

SELECT DISTINCT d.did,d.dname,dvc.c
FROM Doctors d,DoctorsVisitCount dvc
WHERE dvc.c < (SELECT AVG(dvc.c)
               FROM DoctorsVisitCount dvc);
```